# How to get the exact return value of a Pig script and use it for further processing?

Tags: shell, hadoop, error-handling, apache-pig

I know that  Pig returns different code upon completion for these scenarios:

Return code 0: All jobs succeeded
Return code 1: Used for retrievable errors
Return code 2: All jobs have failed
Return code 3: Some jobs have failed

In my code, I want to take an appropriate action, based on the success of a MapReduce job. How to go about doing it?

Pig errors are saved in logs, however, what mechanism should I use to kknow about successfully executed pig scripts ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running your pig scripts using shell scripts, you can check the status of the last executed script and if that returns 0 then only you can proceed to second step, If the first step fails it can show an error message.

```
./pig_script.sh

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Succesfully finished"
else
    echo "Failed"
fi
```

If you are using any frame works or scheduling tools like Oozie or Autosys there are different ways of dealing it.

Comment: If you want to build a pipeline of pig jobs, I would advocate the use of Oozie (or a similar tool).